# SQL "GROUP BY" and "INNER JOIN" Statements together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables of ANIMAL and NEED:

```
        ANIMAL                                      NEED        
Name    Species         Birthday                A_Species      Type 
Koala1  Phascolarctidae 02-10-2014           Phascolarctidae    Veg.    
Bear1   Ursinae         03-10-2016           Ursinae            Veg.    
Koala2  Phascolarctidae 04-09-2015           Ursinae            Meet    
Cattle1 Bovidae         20.03.2017           Ursinae            Fish    
Whale1  Cetacea         08.05.2010           Bovidae            Veg.    
                                             Cetacea            Fish
```

I would like to select the following table

```
    Name    Type                
    Koala1  Veg.                
    Koala2  Veg.                
    Cattle1 Veg.                
    Whale1  Fish
```

which is the list of name of animal and their food that needs only one type of food!

I have to combine two statement of

```
SELECT A_Species 
FROM NEED GROUP BY A_Species
HAVING COUNT(A_Species)=1;
```

and

```
SELECT ANIMAL.NAME, NEED.Type 
FROM ANIMAL 
INNER JOIN NEED ON ANIMAL.Species = NEED.A_Species;
```

I tried

```
SELECT ANIMAL.NAME, NEED.Type 
FROM ANIMAL 
INNER JOIN NEED ON ANIMAL.Species = NEED.A_Species 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT A_Species 
FROM NEED GROUP BY A_Species
HAVING COUNT(A_Species)=1);
```

which it is not working!
Can you help me how can I put them together?

Comment: Why Bear1 is excluded in output? Why last row doesn't have Name and Birthday?

Comment: Your sample data and table layout don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT a.NAME, MAX(n.Type)
FROM ANIMAL a INNER JOIN
     NEED n
     ON a.SPECIES = n.A_SPECIES 
GROUP BY a.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Or an alternative uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.NAME, n.Type
FROM ANIMAL a INNER JOIN
     NEED n
     ON a.SPECIES = n.A_SPECIES 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM need n2
                  WHERE n2.A_SPECIES = n.A_SPECIES AND
                        n2.Type <> n.Type
                 );
```

In practice, this probably has better performance, particularly with an index on `need(a_species, type)`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `GROUP BY a.SPECIES` for `HAVING` to restrict result?

Comment: and please what is the difference between `MAX(n.Type)` and `n.Type` alone?

Comment: @HegelF. . . . `nType` in the first query is incorrect because it is not aggregated.  Earlier versions of MySQL accepted that syntax, but fortunately, the newer versions will also generate a syntax error as well (using the default settings).

Comment: So do you mean it could be `MIN` too?

Comment: @HegelF. . . . Because of the `having` clause, only one row matches, so `min()` and `max()` return the same value.

Comment: Thank you. Could we use `GROUP BY a.Name, n.Type` without using an aggregate function here?

Comment: @HegelF. . . . No.  Then the `count()` would be wrong.